# How to GET only custom Field Names from Azure Form Recognizer API?

Tags: ocr, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I trained a Custom Form Recognizer Model. It tests great. But I can't find the API endpoint to call that returns ONLY the key/value pairs for the form I sent the model to analyze.

**Example**:

- I trained a custom model to find `First name` and `Last name` only
- When I POST a PDF to the endpoint:

  - `https://{my-project}.cognitiveservices.azure.com/formrecognizer/documentModels/{my-model}:analyze?api-version=2022-08-31`
- Then view JSON from the `Operation-Location` header:

  - `https://form-rec-ocr-test.cognitiveservices.azure.com/formrecognizer/documentModels/{model-name}/analyzeResults/{GUID}?api-version=2022-08-31`

I get aaaaallll the text on the submitted PDF *instead of* **only** the `First name` and `Last name` fields. I just want the key/value pairs to insert them into a table.

What is the correct API endpoint to call? The API docs [here](https://centralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-2022-08-31/operations/AnalyzeDocument) are focused on pre-build models instead of Custom Models.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, this was not lined out in any documentation I came across. Found the answer in [this video @36:30](https://youtu.be/k9IKJeNJYuU?t=2199).

The data was in the original JSON object, just at line 3300 under the `document` node.

Would simplify things if the Form Recognizer API could return ONLY the `document` array by defining a simple query parameter.